should I use one queue or 4 seperate queues for vulkan?
I'm learning how to use vulkan and was wondering if it would be better to use the general purpose queue family for all of my tasks or use 4 seperate queues.
these are the queue families on my gpu:
family: 0, queues: 1, supports: { graphics , compute , transfer , sparse_binding  }
family: 1, queues: 1, supports: { compute , transfer , sparse_binding  }
family: 2, queues: 2, supports: { transfer , sparse_binding  }
family: 3, queues: 1, supports: {  }
family: 4, queues: 1, supports: {  }

I was thinking about using queue family 0's queue as graphics 1's and compute, and the two queues in family 2 as transfer and sparse binding, is this the right way to go about it?
also, does anyone know what those 2 queue families at the end are used for?

Using multiple queues is always better performance-wise. Even using a separate queue for presentation is beneficial.
